# Can I invoke the delegate method after popViewcontroller?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, delegates

1)  I have two controllers,  fistViewController, secondViewController.

2)  first controller implements the delegate say "xyzDelegate".

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController <xyzDelegate>
```

3) The delegate method in First View Controller refreshes the UIViewTable.

4) First Controller  : Pushing Second View Controller.

```
 SecondviewController *svc = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
 svc.delegate = self;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:svc animated:YES];
```

4) In second View Controller:

```
 id<xyzDelegate> strongDelegate = self.delegate; 

[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
NSLog (@"After popViewControler");

[strongDelegate dateSelected:dateChoosen];  // Invoking Delegate Method.
```

**Question:**

1) Is it the general practice to invoke the delegate method after Popping View Controller?
   as i am refreshing the UITable, once the delegate method is invoked in FirstView Controller.

Comment: Why not when the date is chosen? Or just refresh the table when the first view controller `viewWillAppear:`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, a view controller is an independent unit of screens. Especially if it's switched by navigation-controller. You are expected to reconfigure views to bind their data in one of overriding of `viewWillAppear:` or `viewDidAppear:` method.

Usually `viewDidAppear:` is preferred. Because in many cases, switching view needs reloading of underlying data, and this usually causes asynchronous I/O. In this case, this asynchronous I/O *may* interfere simultaneously performing view-switching animation.

Anyway, if your view setup operation is lightweight, it's fine and better to go with `viewWillAppear:` because it will make your user to wait less.

In this case, IMO, it seems your best bet is just marking to refresh the data on the target view controller, and handle refreshing in the view-controller's `viewDidAppear:` method.

Answer (score 2):

You should call the delegate methods **BEFORE** POP action occurs.

```
    [strongDelegate dateSelected:dateChoosen];
```

popViewControllerAnimated Will call second view controller dealloc method to destroy, where you would release the strongDelegate. So no more strongDelegate to receive the dateSelected: method.

```
   [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```